# XMLRPC pingback.extensions.getPingbacks not work with parameters

Tags: wp-query, xml-rpc, pingbacks

I want to use the `pingback.extensions.getPingbacks` Method with parameters in the url, like post_type or page. I use the code below, but it doesn't work when I want to add a parameter and I get a fault code of 0 and an empty fault string, but it seems to work when I only pass the url without any parameters. Can anyone help me?

```
<?php

require_once 'class-IXR.php';
$rpc = new IXR_Client('http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/xmlrpc.php');



$result = $rpc->query('pingback.extensions.getPingbacks','http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/2018/01/17/hallo-welt/&post_type=something');

if(!$result) {
echo 'Error [' . $rpc->getErrorCode() . ']: ' . $rpc->getErrorMessage();

}

var_dump($rpc->getResponse());


?>
```

The error message

```
Error [0]: array(2) { ["faultCode"]=> int(0) ["faultString"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that WordPress ships with [`WP_HTTP_IXR_CLIENT`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http_ixr_client/) that extends the `IXR_Client`. So replace

```
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-IXR.php';
$rpc = new IXR_Client( 'http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/xmlrpc.php' );
```

with:

```
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-IXR.php';
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-http-ixr-client.php';
$rpc = new WP_HTTP_IXR_CLIENT( 'http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/xmlrpc.php' );
```

Then try replacing:

```
$result = $rpc->query( 
 'pingback.extensions.getPingbacks',
 'http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/2018/01/17/hallo-welt/&post_type=something'
);
```

with

```
$result = $rpc->query( 
 'pingback.extensions.getPingbacks',
 'http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/2018/01/17/hallo-welt/?post_type=something'
);
```

The server method `wp_xmlrpc_server::pingback_extensions_getPingbacks()` uses the [`url_to_postid()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/url_to_postid/) function to convert the url to a post ID. So make sure your url works there!

PS: These days many WordPress users are looking into the new [REST-API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) instead of the [XML-RPC API](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API).